# How to Return two integer

Tags: java, integer, return

In this simple program i cant return 2 integer values , can you help me ?
How can i do ?

```
public class Aritmetica 
{

public static int div(int x , int y)

  { 

    int q = 0 ;
    int r = x ; 
    while ( r >= y ) 
    {
      r = r - y ;  
      q = q + 1 ;  

    }
    return r && q; **// Here i want to return x and y**
 }

public static void main(String[ ] args)
 {

 if ( ( x <=0 ) & ( y > 0 ) )

  throw new IllegalArgumentException ( " X & Y must be >0  " ) ;

  int res4= div(x,y);

  System.out.println( " q and r : "+ res4) ; **// and here i want to display q and r** 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning two integers at once, you can write separate methods for each operation. For example:

```
public static int div1(int x , int y) { 

// i replaced r with x for readibility
   while ( x >= y ) {
       x = x - y ;  
   }
   return x; // this is your variable r
}

public static int div2(int x, int y) {
    int q = 0;
    int r = x;
    while ( r >= y ) {
        r = r - y ;  // r is required here because it is your update statement in while loop
        q = q + 1 ;  
    }
    return q;
}
```

In your main method, all you have to is call each method (div1 and div2 to get variables r and q, respectively). You can then print them with a statement like:

```
System.out.println( " q and r : "+ div2(x,y) + " and " + div1(x,y)) ;
```

I hope this is simple enough to understand. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works ! And it is very simple , because i started to study java for 2 weeks, and im quite noob ;)

Answer (score 5):

Create a result type: `DivisionResult`, as follows:

```
class DivisionResult {
    public final int quotient;
    public final int remaineder;
    public DivisionResult(int quotient, int remainder) {
        this.quotient = quotient;
        this.remainder = remainder;
    }
}
```

and do

```
    ...
    return new DivisionResult(q, r);
}
```

And to print the result:

```
  DivisionResult res4= div(x,y);

  System.out.println("q and r: " + res4.quotient + ", " + res4.remainder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array of integers to return more than one integers.

Like :

```
public int[] method() {  
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};  
    return a;   
}
```

Comment: At school we havent't studied arrays yet , so i cant fo that

Comment: I don't think this is good practice. `result[1]` simply isn't as readable as `result.remainder`.

Comment: @aioobe What about that result[REMAINDER]

Comment: @VikasVerma, almost worse. `REMAINDER` could be confused with the variable containing the actual remainder. `REMAINDER_INDEX` is slighly better, but still a lot worse than creating a `DivisionResult` class and do `result.remainder`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume q and r are less than p(can be any integer greater than q and r)

Now Do it like this

`return result=q*p+r`

Now, in main when you want to print the result

```
print q=result/p
r=result-p*q
```

Comment: It's probably not the best practice but it's kinda fun :)

Comment: i have only to use + and - for doing the division , but ty aniway  , seem it works ;)

Comment: Ya.. It's the usage of modulo arithmetic. Why can't you use multiplication and division. Is it a puzzle or programming exercise. I am sure they would like if you give different solutions

Comment: Because i have to write some while programs using Peano's Axioms